# HTMLBeautify & Sublime - Ignore Empty Lines

Tags: sublimetext3

Taking over some code created by a previous developer and have a massive HTML formatting clean up task to tackle.

I am using Sublime 3 with HTML Beautify extension to auto format this mess.
https://packagecontrol.io/packages/HTMLBeautify

When the extension is triggered, the HTML is properly indented, however, all the **intended empty lines** are removed.

Can anyone provide a setting to ignore intended empty lines when using the HTML Beautify Extension?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: As @OdatNurd so quickly pointed out, the setting `remove_extraline : false` ignores the empty lines when triggering the extension.

GO TO: Preferences > Package Settings > HTMLBeautify > Settings - User
Add line of code in between: {...}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a quick perusal of the settings in the [README](https://github.com/rareyman/HTMLBeautify/blob/master/README.md#settings) for the package, this setting looks like it might do what you want:

> - `remove_extraline` : Set true to remove empty line.

The setting defaults to `true`, so that would seem to indicate that it's trimming empty lines by default, but changing the setting might stop it from doing that.